Can we change the icon of the Brick community
Is it possible to set a custom icon / favicon for the Bricks community ?
if yes, is there any guidelines for the icon (provided by SE or can be any copyleft icon, …) ?

Our icon is already slightly customised compared to most of the other "non-graduated" Stack Exchange sites. As we haven't fully graduated, we're using the standard "speech bubble" icon, however instead of having the site initials in it, we have a 1x1 brick (which is close to, but doesn't impinge on) LEGO's 2x2 brick favicon.
Once we graduate, as per the recent Theme Update announcement, we may well qualify for further enhancements such as custom badge icons, updated favicon, etc.

you already changed it right?

True, and the graduated designs have mostly been deprecated anyway.
